# поиск подстроки без цифр

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, память, вектор

Дан строковый массив из n элементов, где n – натуральное число. Найти в этом массиве самую длинную подстроку, не содержащую цифры.

Я не понимаю как это можно реализовать, не зная количества элементов. Я так понимаю, что надо сначала реализовать ввод количества символов с клавиатуры, затем необходимо считать с клавиатуры данные, поместить все это дело в массив типа char размером с длиной строки, и поместить подстроки, не содержащие цифр в контейнер вектор, затем найти самую длинную такую строку.

Застрял на том, что не знаю как заполнить контейнер элементами посимвольно и превратить это все в строковый контейнер. То бишь допустим кол-во символов равно 10, вводим строку: asd456h78i. Контейнер q заполняется посимвольно, там лежат `'a'`, `'s'`, `'d'`, `'h'`, `'i'`. Надо теперь завести новый контейнер допустим `conteiner` и чтоб там было вот так: `conteiner[0] = "asd"`, `conteiner[1] = "h"`, `conteiner[2] = "i"` и тд. + Надо как то надо подсчитать количество букавок в каждой ячейке, допустим `conteiner[0] содержит 3 буквы` + надо как то учесть, что количество строк с максимальной длиной может быть больше 1

```
int n;
cin >> n;
char *a = new char[n+1];


vector<char> q;
gets_s(a,n+1);
cin.getline(a, n+1);
for (int i = 0, len = strlen(a); i < len; i++)
{
    if (isdigit(a[i]))  continue;


    while (!isdigit(a[i]))
    {
        q.push_back(a[i]);
        if (i == len)
            break;
        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< q.size(); i++)
        cout << q[i] << endl;
    q.clear();
}
delete[] a;
_getch();
```

Comment: Вам нужно вывести самые длинные подстроки, или достаточно будет только их длины?

Comment: Да, именно вывести, потому что необходима последующая работа с этими строками

Comment: Вы используете `vector`, но не используете для строк класс `string`. Это принципиально нужно (обходиться си-строками)? Если да, тогда я бы предложил использовать функцию `strtok()` с разделителями-цифрами. В цикле будете получать каждый раз подстроку, к которой можете применить `strlen()`. Ну и понадобятся 2 доп. переменных - одна будет хранить длину максимальной строки, другая - саму строку. Если же можно использовать и `string`, то вместо `strtok()` будет удобнее взять функции-методы, типа `find_first_of()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string s = "675Has12 a strong desire to2 learn and explore44 new technologies " ;
    set<string> res;
    auto first = s.begin();
    string vs;
    while ( first != s.end() ) {
        // если первый символ цифра, то находим символ нецифру
        if (isdigit(*first))
            first = find_if(first, s.end(), [](char c) { return !isdigit(c); });
        auto last = find_if(first, s.end(), [](char c) { return isdigit(c); });
        // получаем строку без цифр
        vs = accumulate(first, last,   string());
        res.insert(vs);
        first = last;
    }
    cout << *res.begin(); // ваше самое длинное слово

    return 0;
}
```

и еще :
`"Дан строковый массив из n элементов, где n – натуральное число"` - 
Саму собой разуммется, что `n` не только натуральное, но и целое без знака, если оно представляет количество элементов...